# Writing to the file system is taking too long

Tags: android, multithreading, performance, io, storage

I am trying to download around 300-400 image files using the optimal number of threads(around 20-30) and then writing these images into the file system of Android. The problem is that the whole process is taking 10-13 minutes and I want to clock it around 2-3 minutes with high-speed internet
I think this can be achieved as the size of those 300-400 image files is in some KBs only(total size would be around 80-100 MB)
Here's my code for downloading and saving file

```
            long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

            Call<ResponseBody> call=apiService.fetchAttachmentDetail(att_id,token,true,device_id, 0.0f, 0.0f);

            Response<ResponseBody> response = call.execute();
            long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Help.E("downloaded " + att_id + "and time taken in mili second " + (t2 - t1));
            Help.E("content length- " + response.body().contentLength());

            String str = response.headers().get("Content-Type");
            if (str == null)
                str = "/png";
            String ext_type = str.substring(str.indexOf("/") + 1);
            InputStream in = null;
            FileOutputStream out = null;
            ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(context);
            String fileName = "";
            File directory = cw.getDir(AttachmentDirName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            try {
                in = response.body().byteStream();
                fileName = String.valueOf(att_id) + "." + ext_type;
                File file = new File(directory, fileName);
                out = new FileOutputStream(file);

                int c;
                while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
                    out.write(c);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("Error", e.toString());
                emitter.onError(e);
            } finally {
                if (in != null) {
                    in.close();
                }
                if (out != null) {
                    out.close();
                }
            }

            long t3 = System.currentTimeMillis();

            Help.E("saved " + att_id + "time taken in saving the file " + (t3 - t2));
```

Comment: `using the optimal number of threads(around 20-30) `. Hard to believe. On how many cores? Please tell us how you found 20-30 to be optimal.

Comment: I don't know what the optimal number should be but I ran this code with 20, 30, 50, 100 threads and found that if we create a large number of threads then thread creation overheads increase the overall time but with 20-30 threads, those 300-400 images can be downloaded parallelly. Correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: You did not tell on how many cores. And you did not explain why 20-30 are optimal. Well i think that is not optimal at all. `don't know what the optimal number should be `. Well you can easily test it out. Just try. It is not 20-30.

Comment: Quad-core 1.4 GHz Cortex-A53!!! Could you please tell the optimal number of threads for this core configuration.

Comment: No i cant. Two per core would do i think.  But test it out. So easy to test. First determine the number of cores and then decide how many threads per core. But first use Vladyslav's code. So strange you did not react on that answer.

Comment: I implemented that and it worked perfectly! Thanks to both of you :)

Comment: Please tell how many minutes it takes now.

Comment: It took 1 minute 35 seconds with 20 threads, 1 minute 37 seconds with 8 threads and 1 minute 43 seconds with 4 threads!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading and writing your data byte by byte, it takes significantly more time compared with reading and writing with a buffer. Try to use this method:

```
public static void copyStream(InputStream input, OutputStream output)
    throws IOException
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; // Adjust if you want
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer)) != -1)
    {
        output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
}
```

So you replace your

```
int c;
while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
   out.write(c);
}
```

with

```
copyStream(in, out);
```